# Map array by nested array object property, to an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Having this array of objects containing nested arrays:

```
let arr = [{
  name: "aaa",
  inputs: [{
    inputName: "input-1",
    groups: [{
      groupName: "group-a"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: "bbb",
  inputs: [{
    inputName: "input-2",
    groups: [{
      groupName: "group-b"
    }]
  }]
}];
```

How to map it and return an array of strings containing the **groupName** value, like this:

```
 ['group-a', 'group-b']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [{name:"aaa",inputs:[{inputName:"input-1",groups:[{groupName:"group-a"}]}]},{name:"bbb",inputs:[{inputName:"input-2",groups:[{groupName:"group-b"}]}]}];

const res = arr.flatMap(
  o => o.inputs.flatMap(
    o => o.groups.map(o => o.groupName)
  )
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must flat your arrary twice and then map the final result

```
arr.flatMap(x=>x.inputs).flatMap(x=>x.groups).map(x=>x.groupName)
```

Comment: or arr.flatMap(x=>x.inputs.flatMap(s=>s.groups.map(x=>x.groupName)))

Answer (score 0):

You may use map function of Array.

```js
let arr = [{
    name: "aaa",
    inputs: [{
      inputName: "input-1",
      groups: [{
        groupName: "group-a"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    name: "bbb",
    inputs: [{
      inputName: "input-2",
      groups: [{
        groupName: "group-b"
      }]
    }]
  }];

  newArr = [] 
arr.map( element =>{
    console.log( "element" , element )
    newArr.push( element.inputs[0].groups[0].groupName  )
})

console.log( newArr , "newArr"  )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop to all elements in the array and add their `groupName` to an array like so :

```js
let arr = [{
    name: "aaa",
    inputs: [{
      inputName: "input-1",
      groups: [{
        groupName: "group-a"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    name: "bbb",
    inputs: [{
      inputName: "input-2",
      groups: [{
        groupName: "group-b"
      }]
    }]
  }];

let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.push(arr[i].inputs[0].groups[0].groupName);
}
console.log(result);
```