# Filter complex array in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, sorting

I have array .

```
const arr = [{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [{
            "name": "user1",
            "games": [{
                "id": 1,
                "gamename": "cricket"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "gamename": "football"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "user1",
            "games": [{
                "id": 1,
                "gamename": "videogames"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "gamename": "volleyball"
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried following the code to filter it. and no output show

```
arr.map((item,idx) => (
  
       console.log(item.data.games.gamename)
   )
  ))
```

I want to print all game name  eg.

cricket
football
videogames
volleyball

Comment: try to map also 'item.data' ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map array by nested array object property, to an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67526509/map-array-by-nested-array-object-property-to-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `flatMap()` to do it

```js
const arr = [{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [{
            "name": "user1",
            "games": [{
                "id": 1,
                "gamename": "cricket"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "gamename": "football"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "user1",
            "games": [{
                "id": 1,
                "gamename": "videogames"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "gamename": "volleyball"
            }]
        }
    ]
}]

// multiple flatMap chain invocation seems ugly,waiting for more elegant solution
let result = arr.flatMap(a => a.data).flatMap(a => a.games).flatMap(a => a.gamename)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is a array and so is games:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    status: "success",
    data: [
      {
        name: "user1",
        games: [
          {
            id: 1,
            gamename: "cricket",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            gamename: "football",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "user1",
        games: [
          {
            id: 1,
            gamename: "videogames",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            gamename: "volleyball",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

arr.map((item) => {
  item.data.map((item) => {
    item.games.map((item) => {
      console.log(item.gamename);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code, it will return only game names, you can change the join if don't need comma (,)

Output :
"cricket,football,videogames,volleyball"

```
const arr = [{
"status": "success",
"data": [{
        "name": "user1",
        "games": [{
            "id": 1,
            "gamename": "cricket"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "gamename": "football"
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "user1",
        "games": [{
            "id": 1,
            "gamename": "videogames"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "gamename": "volleyball"
        }]
    }
]
}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.filter(e=>e.status=="success").map(e=>e.data.map(f=>f.games.map(g=>g.gamename)).join(",")).join(",")));
```